# C2280 'winrt::hstring::hstring(std::nullptr_t)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp-xaml, c++-cx, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

in cppcx, I have this piece of code:

```
auto frame = ref new Frame();
frame->Navigate(TypeName(CppCxInternalRefClass::typeid), ref new AnotherCppCxInternalRefClass(a, b, c,
                    ...));
```

which I am trying to convert to cppwinrt like this:

```
Frame frame;
frame.Navigate(
                utils::from_cx<winrt::TypeName>(TypeName(CppCxInternalRefClass::typeid)),
                utils::from_cx<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement>(
                    ref new AnotherCppCxInternalRefClass(a, b, c,
                    ...)));
```

But I am getting an error:

> Error C2280   'winrt::hstring::hstring(std::nullptr_t)': attempting to
> reference a deleted function

This is the function and line where I am getting the error:

```
template <typename T>
T from_cx(Platform::Object ^ from) {
===>T to{nullptr};
    winrt::guid iid = winrt::guid_of<T>();
    winrt::check_hresult(reinterpret_cast<::IUnknown*>(from)->QueryInterface(
        reinterpret_cast<GUID&>(iid), reinterpret_cast<void**>(winrt::put_abi(to))));
    return to;
```

Looks like C++/CX we were able to get the typeid of a class by just doing ClassName:typeId which this code is doing. So there was a  TypeName constructor which took it as an argument. But after changing to a struct in cppwinrt, it is expecting initializers for the two struct variables. I wasnt sure how to deal with this especially with ref classes in this code which my codebase is not ready to port to cppwinrt yet because of lack of support for idls at the moment. So I decided to just have the cppcx code but use the helper functions to convert them, but face this error while conversion.

But if I change the approach to something like this:

```
auto cppCxFrame = utils::to_cx<Frame>(frame);
            cppCxFrame->Navigate(TypeName(CppCxInternalRefClass::typeid),
                ref new AnotherCppCxInternalRefClass(a, b, c, ...));
```

it builds fine.

Comment: You are probably looking for the [xaml_typename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/xaml-typename) function template.

Comment: my understanding is thats for a winrt type. InternalRefClass and AnotherInternalRefClass are c++/cx ref classes which havent been converted to winrt classes yet.

Comment: what i tried to say is that Internal ref class and AnotherInternalRefClass are C++/CX style ref classes. I am trying to convert code that use it to c++/winrt without changing the ref classes. i updated the description as well.

Comment: Do you mean you want to implement the conversion from C++/CX to C++/WinRT in a C++/CX project? You coud refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-cx) for more information about the conversion between C++/CX and C++/WinRT. In addition, based on your description, currently, you can build the project successfully, right?

Comment: I have a workaround, where I convert the fram to a CX object and call navigate on it. But it would be cleaner if I can get this line to work: utils::from_cx<winrt::TypeName>(TypeName(CppCxInternalRefClass::typeid))

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a projection of the C++/CX classes via a winmd, then this is would be easy. Assuming you can't do that, you'll need to convert from a C++/CX `TypeName` to a C++/WinRT `TypeName`. The basic `from_cx` won't do that, because `TypeName` is a struct, not a runtimeclass, but it's straightforward to add overloads of `from_cx` to handle the `TypeName` struct, and the `hstring` it holds.

```cpp
winrt::hstring from_cx(Platform::String^ const& from)
{
  winrt::hstring to;
  const HSTRING& fromHstring = reinterpret_cast<HSTRING>(from);
  winrt::copy_from_abi(to, fromHstring);
  return to;
}

winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName from_cx(::Windows::UI::Interop::TypeName const& from)
{
  return {
    static_cast<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeKind>(from.Kind),
    from_cx(from.Name)
  };
}
```